# How can I check if the user logged in successfully in Axosoft using AxosoftAPI.NET Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, axosoft

I am trying to check if the user is successfully logged in to Axosoft. The code bellow never throws an error, even if the user provides the wrong credentials.

```
public void Login(string user, string pwd)
{
    try
    {
        AxoClient.ObtainAccessTokenFromUsernamePassword
        (
            username: user,
            password: pwd,
            scope: ScopeEnum.ReadWrite
        );
    }
    catch (AxosoftAPIException<ErrorResponse> ex)
    {
        ErrorResponse er = new ErrorResponse();
        er.Error = ex.Source;
        er.ErrorDescription = ex.StackTrace;
        er.Message = ex.Message;
        throw new AxosoftAPIException<ErrorResponse>(er);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

After a login you can get the value of the **HasAccessToken** in **Proxy**.

If you **successfully** logged in it will **return true**, otherwise it'll **return false**.

```
Proxy AxoClient = new Proxy
                {
                    Url = "http://url",
                    ClientId = "ClientId",
                    ClientSecret = "ClientSecret",
                };

AxoClient.ObtainAccessTokenFromUsernamePassword
                (
                    username: user,
                    password: pwd,
                    scope: ScopeEnum.ReadWrite
                );

MessageBox.Show(AxoClient.HasAccessToken);
```

I hope this will help others.